# Convert binary to IP-address

Tags: binary, ip-address, bit

The binary string below should be a (hidden) IP-address in anyway. How do I convert it to decimal? Since the number containsto many octets I dont know how to convert it. It should lead to this IPv4:
83.226.175.75

binary string:
    001101110011010001110101001100000100010001101011011010100011001001010001

but it makes no sense! The first 8 bits in the string refers to decimal 55, and the IP-address should begin with 83. can we find a general rule to link this length of binary numbers to an IP address? Well, it cannot be IPv6, the string is to short...

Comment: how did you come upon this binary string?

Comment: What do you know about the encoding of the bits string? Bit order, byte order of the source archtecture. Furthermore, you show 72 bits, potentially 9 8bit bytes. That for sure is quite _uncommon_. Usually ip addresses are encoded as a sequence of 4 bytes. A character encoding woud use 13 bytes in your example. So, please, give more background on the construction of the bit string.